# How to realize the tableView's cell margin the left and right periphery of the tableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

This is my requirement:

[image]

I want my tableView's cell to be like the last cell, its border is margin the tableView some pix, not contradict the tableview's edge.(I want this is because when I click down the cell, there is gray effect on the cell)

How to do with that?

Comment: What do you want? The gray highlight not to happen on tapping the cell? Or you are unable to make cells as they appear in the screenshot?

Comment: @Rikh I mean, I want to the cell left and right have a margin to the tableview's edge, if not, when I tap down the cell the gray color will fill the first red framework, but I want when I tap down the cell, the gray scope only in the 3rd cell red frame shows.

Comment: You can maintain by programmatically, Which row you clicked you can identify and make it gray background and remaining white color. And for Edges you can make it for images which you added in cell and how much you need space in left and right, and check once UIImageView properties how you gave.

Comment: @Haric Do you mean I can realize it ? but how to add the gray effect to the specified view I want (in the cell)?

Comment: By using flags you can do it, In you are array of dictionaries take one flag like **IsSelect  == No**, When you click row set it **IsSelect  == YES** , Then **reload table**, In **cellforRowAtindexpath** you can check and do gray or white.

Answer (score 0):

u can't resize the cell's, instead u can set the views's layer properties to achieve the similar effect, for example, (u are not mentioning which language u are using, i assume u are using swift).

i will assume your custom cell contains a UIView and some other view components, like below,

[image]

and also add outlet for `imageHolderView` in the above image,
out let name will be `holderView` as shown in below image,

[image]

in the custom cell class, define two methods for selection management, and your custom cell class would look like below,

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var circleNameTextField: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var holderView: UIView!
  var cellindexPath:IndexPath?
  var selectedIndexPath:IndexPath?


  func selectTheCell() {
    if self.selectedIndexPath?.row == self.cellindexPath?.row {
        self.holderView.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0
        self.holderView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.holderView.layer.borderWidth = 4.0
        self.holderView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    } else {
        self.resetCellWith(animate: false)
    }
 }

 func resetCellWith(animate:Bool) {

     self.holderView.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0
     self.holderView.layer.masksToBounds = false
     self.holderView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
     self.holderView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
 }
}
```

now all u have to do is call the above methods, from controller and update the cell behaviour, for example,

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.selIndexPath = indexPath
    self.aTableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .none)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : CustomCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CUSTOM_CELL", for: indexPath) as? CustomCell//tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CUSTOM_CELL") as? CustomCell

    cell?.cellindexPath = indexPath

    if let selectedIndexPath = self.selIndexPath {
        cell?.selectedIndexPath = selectedIndexPath
        cell?.selectTheCell()
    } else {
        cell?.resetCellWith(animate:false)
    }
    cell?.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell!
}
```

with the above arrangement, u can get the table cell and selection like below,

[image]

NOTE: well, above is one way achieve this effect. and method names i simply used the sample project that i created for different purpose. :)